# Caching instances in a Java EE web app

Tags: jsf, caching, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

Consider the scenario of a typical webapp with JSFs on the front and EJB 3, with Hibernate as JPA provider, talking to backend database such as mysql, etc. The main user actions are login and mostly CRUD operations (minus any D(elete) operations). And the App Server is GlassFish of course.

Given this scenario, how and where all would one go about providing caching to improve performance? From what I have googled, I have seen that hibernate provides some sort of caching through different cache providers. Is there any sort of caching that can be provided for the jsf pages? How about session beans or entity beans on the ejb side of things?

Also, I just read about memcached and was wondering if this was something to consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article on [second level caching by Jacob Orshalick](http://solutionsfit.com/blog/2009/04/06/second-level-caching-still-an-effective-performance-tuning-technique/) is worth a read.

Seam has a JSF tag `<s:cache>` that allows page-fragment caching. The [caching chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/reference/en-US/html/cache.html) of the Seam Docs is also worth reading.